# Examples of ‘kangaroo etymologies’ that actually happened

Tags: terminology, reference-request, borrowing

There’s an urban legend that the word *kangaroo* is from an Aboriginal phrase that means, “I don’t know.” This is not true: the word is actually from a Guugu Yimithirr word for a particular species of kangaroo, *gangurru*.

But are there any known cases of this kind of thing really happening? That is, a misunderstanding or lack of understanding of another language leading to a term being borrowed for something even though it has a totally different meaning in the source language.

My guess is that well-documented cases are likely rare, because either,

- the exact etymology would be hard to track if it’s based on true mistakes, or
- the mistake would have been corrected if found to be wrong.

If I want to search for this phenomenon in literature, what would be the best terminology to look for?

Comment: if they are very rare, they are indeed lonewords :)

Comment: Check the stories of why the Slavic languages' [word for ‘elephant’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/slonъ) is actually a borrowing from the Turkic word for ‘lion’ and why the Slavic [word for ‘camel’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/верблюд#Etymology_2) is actually a borrowing from the Gothic word for ‘elephant’.

Comment: What terminology to look for?

Comment: There are endless loans where we know the meaning has shifted.  It's harder to know if it shifted from the very beginning or just soon after.

Answer (score 4):

In French, the name for a certain type of window is *le vasistas*, almost certainly from German *was ist das?* ("what is that?"), inquiring about that particular type of window (which is far more common in France than in Germany).

Comment: Not only is this folk (though I have no better etymology the uncertainty of *fenetre* "window" stands to reason, and L. *viso* "I see" is most likely the root), but it is told wrong. Following one comment on r/etymology, "Was ist das" would be the inquiry heard from a tenant looking through a small *window* above the door, "What is it?".

Comment: @vectory I have no idea what you mean by “the uncertainty stands to reason”; did a word get lost?

Comment: I am not a hundred percent familiar with the language spoken by Sgt. "Nobby" Nobbs but I believe that “stands to reason” is a simple Positive Polarity Item. *The uncertainty of* fenetre *yes*. Okay, that sounds stupid.

Comment: @vectory If transom windows are more common in France than in Germany, why would it be named after the German expression?

Comment: Perhaps Lothringen for one has a history of different affiliations, so France vs Germany is a red herring.

Answer (score -5):

> But are there any known cases of this kind of thing really happening?

"this thing" is far *too broad*. The general idea is *Folk Etymology*. The word itself is a neat example.

*Folk* or German *Volk* (Volksetymology) have different connotations. The coinage of *Volksetymology* is often credited to Förstemann (Zeitschrift für vergleichende Sprachforschung auf dem Gebiete der Indogermanischen Sprachen, 1852). French *etymologie populaire* appears some time later, possibly mediated by English. Wiktionary credits *folk etymology* to Smythe Palmer (1882) in turn "from a calque of German *Volksetymologie* (1820s, in 1821 as *Volks-Etymologie* in J. A. Schmeller's *Die Mundarten Bayerns grammatisch dargestellt*)".

Förstemann, clearly reinventing the wheel, defines *Volksetymologie* as a form of *corruption*, e.g. *woodchuck* for Cree *ocêk, otchek*, and was lauded for summarizing a slew of similar concepts. He pitted *Volk* "the people" against the *learned* (“gelehrte”) and  the *scholarly* (“wissenschaftlich”). I am not sure what Schmeller said.

Anyhow, Englisch *folk* has on the other hand a connotation of tradition, e.g. *folk story, tale*, not unlike Ger. *Volksmärchen*. In particular, *Volksweisheit* may be translated variously as "folk wisdom" (dict.cc) or "wisdom of the crowds" (common knowledge? majority opinion?) but “saying, idiom, aphorism, maxim" (collins: *Spruch*) is closer to the truth (“[…]  im Volke überlieferte Sentenz”, Wörterbuch der Deutschen Gegenwartssprache: *Volksweisheit*).

Meanwhile, Wiktionary has *folk etymology* "also known as (generative) popular etymology, analogical reformation, (morphological) reanalysis and etymological reinterpretation" and distinguishes it from *false etymology* "or pseudo-etymology". *Rebracketing*, *mondegreen*, *egghorn* and more have separate entries, which makes for a confusing situation. *Ex falso quodlibet*. The folk element remains important because any legend has a kernel of truth which distinguishes it from *false etymology*.

---

As for *kangaroo etymology* or, there are many stories of one language's "What? I don't know" being handled as pseudo-etymology in another language's lexicon.

Hypothesis:

> the mistake would have been corrected if found to be wrong.—*OP*

This is very likely true in the trivial case.

However, it is at least possible that *kangaroo* became reanalyzed as something like "false" as in *kangaroo court* and eventually repurposed for etymology. The etymology of *kangaroo court* remains obscure, anyway.

---

Examples of mistranslations taking root so as to be true etymology will be left as exercise to the reader until further notice.